# How do you apply a recursive formatting with Go Templates (Helm)?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm using helm and given a yaml object I want to flatten it while applying some recursive formatting.

Given this:

```yaml
some_map:
  with: different
  indentation:
    levels: and
  nested:
    sub: 
      maps: "42"
    and_more:
      maps: 42
```

I want to (for example) get this:

```ini
some_map.with="different"
some_map.indentation.levels="and"
some_map.nested.sub.maps="42"
some_map.nested.and_more.maps=42
```

I haven't read anything about recursive looping in the helm docs, keep in mind that the format of the recursion in the example ( "%v.%v" if !root else "%v=%v" ) may vary.

Comment: If you haven't already, it may be worth opening [a Sprig issue](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/issues) to see what their appetite is for including `toToml` to go along with its `toJson` and `toYaml` friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach

**_helpers.tpl:**

```
 {{- define "template.flattenFn" -}}
  {{- $ctx := . -}}
  {{- if or (eq (kindOf .data) "map") (eq (kindOf .data) "slice") }}
    {{- range $key, $value := .data }}
      {{- include "template.flattenFn" (dict "prefixes" (append $ctx.prefixes $key) "data" $value ) }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- else }}
    {{-   printf "\"%s\":%s, "  (join "__" .prefixes) (toJson .data) }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "template.flatten" -}}
 {{- include "template.flattenFn" (dict "prefixes" list "data" . ) }} 
{{- end -}}
```

**values.yaml**

```
  environment_map:
    Log:
      Level:
        Default: Debug
      Target:
      - Name: Console
        Args:
          formatter: "JsonFormatter"
```

**usage**

```
{{- range $env, $value := include "template.flatten" .Values.environment_map | fromYaml }}
  - name: {{ $env }}
    value: {{ $value | quote }}
```

**result**

```
    - name: Log__Level__Default
      value: "Debug"
    - name: Log__Target__0__Args__formatter
      value: "JsonFormatter"
    - name: Log__Target__0__Name
      value: "Console"
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @prog76 .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems that `{{ define` supports recursive use of `{{ include`, although unknown to what depth

The PoC I whipped up to see if it could work

```
{{- define "bob" -}}
{{- $it := . -}}
{{- $knd := kindOf . -}}
{{- if eq $knd "map" }}
{{- range (keys .) }}
{{- $k := . }}
{{- $v := get $it . }}
{{- $vk := kindOf $v }}
{{- if eq $vk "map" }}
{{-   printf "%s." $k }}
{{-   include "bob" $v }}
{{- else }}
{{-   printf "%s=%s\n" $k (toJson $v) }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- else }}
{{ toJson . }}#k({{ $knd }})
{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

invoked as

```yaml
{{ $fred := dict 
    "alpha" (dict "a0" "a0ch0")
    "beta" (dict "beta0" (dict "beta00" 1234))
    "charlie" (list "ch0" "ch1" "ch2") }}
data:
  theData: |
{{ toJson $fred | indent 4 }}
  toml: |
{{ include "bob" $fred | indent 4 }}
```

produced

```yaml
data:
  theData: |
    {"alpha":{"a0":"a0ch0"},"beta":{"beta0":{"beta00":1234}},"charlie":["ch0","ch1","ch2"]}
  toml: |
    alpha.a0="a0ch0"
    beta.beta0.beta00=1234
    charlie=["ch0","ch1","ch2"]
```

Also, your cited example seems to make reference to the outermost variable name, which I don't think helm knows about, so you'd need an artificial wrapper `dict` in order to get that behavior: `{{ include "toToml" (dict "some_map" .Values.some_map) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mdaniel for his answer, which helped/allowed me to fix my problem! His (quick, I get it) solution has problem though if you have move values with same prefix. To carry on with his example:

```
{{ $fred := dict
    "alpha" (dict "a0" "a0ch0")
    "beta" (dict "beta0" (dict "beta00" 1234))
    "charlie" (list "ch0" "ch1" "ch2")
    "problem" (dict "beta0" (dict "1" "1" "2" "2" )) }}
data:
  theData: |
{{ toJson $fred | indent 4 }}
  toml: |
{{ include "bob" $fred | indent 4 }}
```

will produce:

```
data:
  theData: |
    {"alpha":{"a0":"a0ch0"},"beta":{"beta0":{"beta00":1234}},"charlie":["ch0","ch1","ch2"],"problem":{"beta0":{"1":"1","2":"2"}}}
  toml: |
    problem.beta0.1="1"
    2="2"
    alpha.a0="a0ch0"
    beta.beta0.beta00=1234
    charlie=["ch0","ch1","ch2"]
```

which is not correct. Also there is another eye-candy problem of lost order, no idea why or how to fix it, but that's not such biggie.

My extra requirement was, that I needed to add common prefix to all lines. Without it you can define another template simplifying usage, but that's trivial to do.

**disclaimer**: I'm totally new to helm/go-templating, so following isn't probably optimal, but it should fix these issues.

To carry on with example again:

```
{{ $fred := dict
    "alpha" (dict "a0" "a0ch0")
    "beta" (dict "beta0" (dict "beta00" 1234))
    "charlie" (list "ch0" "ch1" "ch2")
    "problem" (dict "beta0" (dict "1" "1" "2" "2" )) }}
data:
  theData: |
{{ toJson $fred | indent 4 }}
  toml: |
{{ include "flattenYaml" (dict "prefix" "added_prefix" "data" $fred) | indent 4 }}
```

will produce:

```
data:
  theData: |
    {"alpha":{"a0":"a0ch0"},"beta":{"beta0":{"beta00":1234}},"charlie":["ch0","ch1","ch2"],"problem":{"beta0":{"1":"1","2":"2"}}}
  toml: |
    added_prefix.alpha.a0="a0ch0"
    added_prefix.beta.beta0.beta00=1234
    added_prefix.charlie=["ch0","ch1","ch2"]
    added_prefix.problem.beta0.1="1"
    added_prefix.problem.beta0.2="2"
```

and template source for flattenYaml looks like this:

```
{{- define "flattenYaml" -}}
{{- $dict := . -}}
{{- $prefix := $dict.prefix -}}
{{- $data := $dict.data -}}
{{- $knd := kindOf $data -}}
    {{- if eq $knd "map" }}
        {{- range (keys $data) }}
            {{- $key := . }}
            {{- $prefixedKey := (printf "%s.%s" $prefix $key) }}
            {{- $value := get $data $key }}
            {{- $valueKind := kindOf $value }}
            {{- if eq $valueKind "map" }}
                {{-   include "flattenYaml" (dict "prefix" ($prefixedKey) "data" $value) }}
            {{- else }}
                {{-   printf "%s=%s\n" $prefixedKey (toJson $value) }}
            {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
    {{- else }}
        {{ toJson . }}#k({{ $knd }})
    {{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

**disclaimer 2**: I have no idea what `#k ...` in `{{ toJson . }}#k({{ $knd }})` from original solution does, do not be surprised if it explodes into your face ;)

**edit:**
the

```
    {{ toJson . }}#k({{ $knd }})
```

actually blew into my face, still don't know what #k should serve, but following replacement fixed my issue:

```
    {{- if ne $data nil }}
        {{- toJson $data }}
    {{- end }}
```